# Unable to upload image using axios in React with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, api, next.js

I am working on Reactjs and Php, Actually i am trying to upload image to server, Image is uploading but whenever i try to open image then showing "we dont support this file format", How can i fix this ?

1. I am sending formdata with multipart form data and in php (api) i am using base64 image for upload image to server
2. Is my apporach for sending image to axios (api) is correct or something wrong with php code

Here is my nextjs code

```
const handleSubmit: FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = async (e) => {
        var imagefile = document.querySelector('#file');
              formData.append("file", imagefile.files[0]);
              const response = await axios({
              method: "post",
              url: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/",
              data: formData,
              headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
              }).then(function (response) {
                alert('respone is '+ response.data.msg);
                 }).catch(function (error) {
               alert('respone is '+ error);
                console.log("failed to get recommend playlist");
                console.log('error is '+ error.msg);
            });
 }
```

And following is my Api code in Php side

```
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), TRUE);
  $files=file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]); 
  $image = base64_decode(explode( ',', $files)[1]);
  define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'uploads/');
 $file_ext = strtolower( end(explode('.',$file_name)));
  $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $image);
  $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
  $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
  $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
  $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.'.$file_ext;
  file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issues is from the PHP. You can just simplify it by using [`pathinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to get the extension and [`move_uploaded_file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to move the uploaded file to the server.

Try this

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'uploads/');
$file_ext  = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$file_name = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . time() . '.' . $file_ext;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $file_name);
```

Comment: not working, uploading image with 0 byte (like empty)

Comment: Do you get any errors @Rick?

Comment: no but downloading image with 0 byte

Comment: Try debugging with `print_r($_FILES['file']);` and let me know what you get